# Error while compiling app for android with buildozer

Tags: python, android, compilation, kivy

I'm trying to compile a kivy painter app for android with buildozer, but I'm getting this error:

```
# Check configuration tokens
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\siuba\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\siuba\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\siuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\buildozer.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\siuba\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\buildozer\scripts\client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "c:\users\siuba\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\buildozer\__init__.py", line 1040, in run_command
    print('Unknown command/target {}'.format(self.translate_target(command, inverse=True)))
AttributeError: 'Buildozer' object has no attribute 'translate_target'
```

Does anyone know how to resolve it?

My configurations:

- Windows 10 64-bit
- Python 3.7.6
- Buildozer https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/archive/afebba5.zip
- Kivy 1.11.1

Answer (score 0):

From the `buildozer` [documentation](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

> You must have a Linux or OSX computer to be able to compile for
> Android.

`Windows` is not supported. You can get around that by making your PC dual boot `Linux` (I use `Ubuntu`) or perhaps by installing [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).